# Distributed Lock Service with Windows Server AppFabric Caching

Tags: caching, appfabric, distributed-caching

I have an extension method for the Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCache object found in the Windows Server AppFabric SDK that looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching;

namespace Caching
{
    public static class CacheExtensions
    {
        private static Dictionary<string, object> locks = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        public static T Fetch<T>(this DataCache @this, string key, Func<T> func)
        {
            return @this.Fetch(key, func, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
        }

        public static T Fetch<T>(this DataCache @this, string key, Func<T> func, TimeSpan timeout)
        {
            var result = @this.Get(key);

            if (result == null)
            {
                lock (GetLock(key))
                {
                    result = @this.Get(key);

                    if (result == null)
                    {
                        result = func();

                        if (result != null)
                        {
                            @this.Put(key, result, timeout);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return (T)result;
        }

        private static object GetLock(string key)
        {
            object @lock = null;

            if (!locks.TryGetValue(key, out @lock))
            {
                lock (locks)
                {
                    if (!locks.TryGetValue(key, out @lock))
                    {
                        @lock = new object();
                        locks.Add(key, @lock);
                    }
                }
            }

            return @lock;
        }
    }
}
```

The intent is to let the developer write code that says, "fetch me some data by trying the cache first. if it's not available in cache execute the specified function, put the results in cache for the next caller, then return the results". Like this:

```
var data = dataCache.Fetch("key", () => SomeLongRunningOperation());
```

The locking limits executing the potentially long running function call to a single thread but only within a single process on the same machine. How would you expand on this pattern to make the locking distributed to prevent multiple processes/machines from executing the function at once?

Answer (score 8):

AppFabric has it's own distributed locking mechanism which you can access through the `GetAndLock/PutAndUnlock` family of methods. If your item is locked, a normal `Get` call will still succeed and return the last value, but further `GetAndLock` calls will throw an Exception. In the case where your client is requesting a cached object for the first time, you can still lock the key even though it doesn't really exist yet (it's kind of more like a *reservation* than a solid lock).

```
public static T Fetch<T>(this DataCache @this, string key, Func<T> func, TimeSpan timeout)
{
    var result = @this.Get(key);

    if (result == null)
    (
        DataCacheLockHandle handle;
        // We need a timespan to allow func time to run
        TimeSpan funcTimespan = New TimeSpan(0,1,0);

        try
        {
            // Lock the key
            // If something goes wrong here it will unlock at the end of funcTimespan
            var result = @this.GetAndLock(key, funcTimespan, handle);

            if (result == null)
            {
                // Still no value so go and run func
                result = func();

                @this.PutAndUnlock(key, result, handle, timeout);
            }
            else
            {
                // There's a value now so we'll unlock the key and reset it's timeout
                @this.Unlock(key, handle, timeout);
            }
        }
        catch (DataCacheException ex)
        {
            if (ex.ErrorCode == DataCacheErrorCode.ObjectLocked)
            {
                // Another process has locked the key so func must be running right now
                // We'll return null to the client
                result = null;
            }
        }

        if (result == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            return (T)result;
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: This is close to what I'm looking for, but I don't want to return null to the client in the case of another process having the key locked. I'd like to wait for the other process to populate the cache, get the value, then return without the caller knowing any different.

Comment: So simply encapsulate retry logic around the GetAndLock behavior. I've done this recently using some Thread.Sleep. Not ideal, but as long as you put a cap on retries to prevent dead threads, should be workable.

Answer (score 4):

I was looking for a good implementation of this and came up with my own:
[Distributed Lock with AppFabric Caching](http://codingsolution.wordpress.com/2013/07/30/distributed-lock-with-appfabric-caching/)

Essentially it's an AcquireLock() extension method to the DataCache class which you can use like this:

```
DataCache cache = factory.GetCache("MyCache");
using (cache.AcquireLock("MyLock"))
{
    // Lock acquired, perform synchronized work here
}
```

Comment: I found this to be a very good solution, exactly what I needed, thank you!

Comment: @Guy Godin : Could you elaborate on "Perform synchronized work here". I'm trying to put an object in different region of the cache with the same key in an atomic way. I've left my code untouched inside the using block but the unlock call in the Dispose() method throws an exception : Object being referred to is not locked by any client.

Comment: @omatrot Perhaps you are accidently moving the entry which you acquired a lock on? By synchronized work I mean only one instance of your service will be doing work at a given time.

Comment: @GuyGodin I'm using cache.Put instead of cache.Add to manage the cache, may be this is the root of the problem.

Comment: @GuyGodin I've managed to make it work by slightly modifying your code to put the object with a key derived from the original one in a specific region to avoid conflicting with code in the synchronized work inside the using block. Works beautifully.

Comment: I definitely appreciate the implementation of this. Seems to do what I need, but like omatrot mentioned, I too had to make a slight change -- instead of locking on the actual cache key, I used a derived key from the original.